# how to remove unknown requests from a vue web app project

Tags: html, json, api, vue.js, core-ui

There are many requests with unknown request url, and misterious file every time I open my vue web app project as seen in this [screenshot](https://ibb.co/Q9SDTHy). How do you track and locate those files and how do I remove them *safely*?
..I'm using Vue 2.6 with Core UI template, my editor is Visual Studio Code

Comment: Those are called chunks. Remove chunking from your webpack configuration. Although, I don't know why you'd want to.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for your response.. that's all i need for I'm new with this thing. 
I also found this link is helpful for me, and for those who need it..

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/648526/All-About-HTTP-Chunked-Responses